# Why the open quote and bracket for eval('(' + jsonString+ ')') when parsing json string

Tags: javascript, json, eval

Can you please tell me the reason for this specific syntax structure

```
 eval('(' + jsonString+ ')')
```

When parsing json text. Crockford says "*The text must be wrapped in parens to avoid tripping on an ambiguity in JavaScript's syntax*."  [here](http://www.json.org/js.html). What does that mean?

Can we avoid it?

Comment: If you continue reading the sentence after the one you've quoted, from the page you've linked to, you'll see why you shouldn't use `eval` for this job *at all*

Comment: That reason for avoid eval is something that I am aware of, Anyway thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The syntax ambiguity to which Crockford refers is that if an open curly brace is not found on *expression* context, it will be recognized like a [block](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_12.1), and not like the start of an object literal.

For example:

```
{"foo": "bar"} // SyntaxError
```

Will give you a syntax error, because it will be interpreted as a block, with a string literal "foo", and a unexpected usage of the token `:`.

On the other hand, the parentheses, formally called [the grouping operator](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.1.6), can only evaluate expressions, therefore we will not have any syntax ambiguity because a block can only be expected on a *statement* context.

```
({"foo": "bar"})
```

---

**Edit:** [@el.pescado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360356/why-the-open-quote-and-bracket-for-eval-jsonstring-when-parsing-json#comment-3490319) makes an interesting question:

> Can you explain why eval('{}') is undefined?

ECMAScript describes an internal type to explain the behavior of statements, it's called [The Completion Specification Type](http://www.ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.9).

Values of the Completion type are triples of the form of `(type, value, target)`, where `type` can be `normal`, `break`, `continue`, `return`, or `throw`.

`value` can be any language value or `empty`, and `target` any Identifier or `empty`.

An empty block (the production [`Block : {}`](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_12.1)) explicitly returns the following completion:

```
Return (normal, empty, empty).
```

The [`eval`](http://www.ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.1.2.1) function, after executing the code, and exiting the newly created execution context, checks the result completion of the evaluated code, and in the Step 7 we can see that `undefined` is explicitly returned if the completion type is `normal` and the completion value is `empty`:

> ...
>
> 7- If result.type is normal and its completion value is empty, then return the value undefined.
>
> ...

Comment: See this never published blog post draft, about the [Completion Type](http://j.mp/gI9IRv)

Answer (score 0):

An object literal needs to be wrapped in parentheses to properly be evaluated in `eval` context and other contexts:

`eval('{}')` is undefined, for example. whereas `eval('(' + '{}' + ')' )` evaluates to Object.

If you tried this in the console, for example: `{"foo":"bar"}` it would throw an invalid label at you. Wrap it in parentheses and it becomes a valid expression.

Comment: Can you explain why `eval('{}')` is undefined?

Comment: @el.pescado: Interesting question, check my [edited answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360356/why-the-open-quote-and-bracket-for-eval-jsonstring-when-parsing-json/3360404#3360404).

Answer (score 0):

@el.pescado, the string after executed by eval should be javascript understandable.
i.e if you are assigning the above string to  the varible as follows

eval(' var foo1 = {"foo" : "bar"}');
foo1.foo will return bar

so, my assumption is, as there is no statement like that starts with "{" in javascript, it is throwing the error.

Comment: A [Block](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_12.1) is considered to be a statement, `eval('{}')` doesn't produce any error, it's only an empty block.

Comment: `var` appears to be illegal in a string you pass to `eval()`, did your code work in some older browser (maybe with ES3 support only)?