# Parse json with gwt 2.0

Tags: json, gwt

i'm trying to parse JSON coming from a flow in my gwt 2.0 application.

What is the best way ? Should I use javascriptobject ? JSonParser ? I'm lost with what I'm founding on the web because there's never the gwt version.

```
String text = "{\"item\":[{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"Bob\"},{\"Id\":\"2\",\"Name\":\"John\"},{\"Id\":\"3\",\"Name\":\"Bill\"}]}";
```

How can I play with my list of items ?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The answer depends on how much you trust that JSON :) Sure, it might be coming from your application, but if insert some untrusted user input, you are facing a possible security hole.

So:

- **for JSONs from trusted sources**, I use [JavaScript Overlay Types](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay.html). They make integrating JSON with GWT seamless and I'd definitely recommend this approach. However, internally, this calls the `eval()` function which means (at least) two things: JSON parsing will be extremely fast (it uses browsers native code for that) and will be possibly insecure. Google for more info about JSON related security issues. [`JSONParser`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONParser.html) can also parse JSON via `eval()`, when you invoke its [`parseLenient(String jsonString)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONParser.html#parseLenient(java.lang.String)) method, but it's definitely less attractive than JSO.
- **for untrusted sources/input**, you should use [`JSONParser`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONParser.html) via [`JSONParser.parseStrict(String jsonString)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONParser.html#parseStrict(java.lang.String)) (available in GWT >=2.1) - you'll have to write more code that way, but you can be sure that the input is properly handled. You might also look into integrating the "official" [JSON parser from json.org](http://www.json.org/js.html) with JSO - write a [JSNI](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html) function that returns the parsed object and cast it to your JSO - in theory it *should* work ;) (that's what GWT does internally with JSOs, at least from what I understood)

As for accessing lists in JSON, there are appropriate classes for that: [`JsArray`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/core/client/JsArray.html) (generic, for lists of other JSOs), [`JsArrayString`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/core/client/JsArrayString.html), etc. If you look at their implementation, they are just JSNI wrappers around the native JS arrays, so they are very fast (but limited, for some reason).

---

*Edit in response to Tim's comment:*

I wrote a simple abstract class that helps to minimize the boilerplate code, when dealing with JSOs and JSON:

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject;

public abstract class BaseResponse extends JavaScriptObject {
    // You can add some static fields here, like status codes, etc.

    /**
     * Required by {@link JavaScriptObject}
     */
    protected BaseResponse() { }

    /**
     * Uses <code>eval</code> to parse a JSON response from the server
     * 
     * @param responseString the raw string containing the JSON repsonse
     * @return an JavaScriptObject, already cast to an appropriate type
     */
    public static final native <T extends BaseResponse> T getResponse(String responseString) /*-{
        // You should be able to use a safe parser here
        // (like the one from json.org)
        return eval('(' + responseString + ')');
    }-*/;
}
```

Then you write your actual JSO as such:

```
import com.example.client.model.User;

public class LoginResponse extends BaseResponse {

    protected LoginResponse() { }

    public final native String getToken() /*-{
        return this.t;
    }-*/;

    public final native int getId() /*-{
        return parseInt(this.u[0]);
    }-*/;

    // ...

    // Helper method for converting this JSO to a POJO
    public final User getUser() {
        return new User(getLogin(), getName(), getLastName());
    }
}
```

And finally in your code:

```
// response.getText() contains the JSON string
LoginResponse loginResponse = LoginResponse.getResponse(response.getText());
// ^ no need for a cast \o/
```

Your JSON looks like this (courtesy of [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com/), a great JSON validator):

```
{
    "item": [
        {
            "Id": "1",
            "Name": "Bob"
        },
        {
            "Id": "2",
            "Name": "John"
        },
        {
            "Id": "3",
            "Name": "Bill"
        }
    ]
}
```

So, I'd write a JSO that describes the items of that list:

```
public class TestResponse extends BaseResponse {

    protected TestResponse() { }

    public final native String getId() /*-{
        return this.Id;
    }-*/;

    public final native String getName() /*-{
        return this.Name;
    }-*/;

    // Static helper for returning just the list
    // Code untested but you should get the idea ;)
    public static final native JsArray<TestResponse> getTestList(String json) /*-{
        var stuff = eval('(' + json + ')');
            return stuff.item;
    }-*/;
}
```

*Then*, in your code you call `TestResponse.getTestList(someJsonString)` and play around with the `JsArray` you get (the `TestResponse`s it contains are created automagically). Cool, eh? ;) It might be a bit confusing at first, but believe me, it will make sense once you start using it and it's *a lot* easier than parsing via `JSONParser` >_>

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm going to use js overlay types.
But how would I translate my json text to get a customer ? In the example, he uses : $wnd.jsonData[0];
In my case I have a string (coming from a RequestBuilder)

Comment: working perfectly, thanks. I missed the eval function.
Best regards

Comment: Why did you use braces around the string in eval? In this code: 
`return eval('(' + responseString + ')');`

Comment: @Davor: Good question! :) I'm no JavaScript expert and I propbably copied that part from somewhere, but [json.org](http://www.json.org/js.html) gives this explanation: `The text must be wrapped in parens to avoid tripping on an ambiguity in JavaScript's syntax`. Related SO questions: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/964397/181497) and [two](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3360356/181497).

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response! Yeah, it didn't work without them for me, so I was wondering what the heck was going on...