# javascript eval and object evaluation

Tags: javascript, eval

I have a part of a debugging framework that needs to be able to run time eval objects.

Specifically, if I have a string like this `"{a: 1, b:2}"` it needs to evaluate it into an object with members `a` and `b` with those values. However, if I do `eval("{a: 1, b:2}")` it seems to evaluate it as a statement, and says something about an illegal label.

I have hacked it so that it evaluates like this:

```
eval("var x=" + str + "; x;");
```

which seems to work, but seems like a horrible hack. Any suggestions on how to do this better?

(BTW, I am aware of the dangers of eval, but this is part of a debugging framework that will not be seen by actual users.)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360356/why-the-open-quote-and-bracket-for-eval-jsonstring-when-parsing-json

Answer (score 32):

You can do it using `()` to have it parse it as an object, rather than a statement, like this:

```
eval("(" + str + ")");
```

Though, you should use `JSON.parse()` first, if the browser supports it.

Comment: JSON.parse() will not work with the examples described because they are not valid JSON. For example, valid JSON encloses all property names in double quotes.

Comment: @idealmachine - yes you're correct...at the same time though, I'd argue if you intend to use it as such, why *not* use valid JSON in the first place?  In this example, yes the user would need to adjust their  object markup.

Comment: Or write a function to convert from JavaScript object notation to JSON (e.g. add quotes). That is easy engough to do.

Comment: Somebody understand why this is so ?