# How to parse JSON easily?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have some JSON encoded strings and I need to easily parse them. Any ideas how to do this? I am a noob in javaScript and I can't do it myself. I read that parsing json is really hard.

Please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serializing to JSON in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)

Answer (score 11):

JSON is valid Javascript, so you can eval() it:

```
var data = eval(json);
```

However it's safer to use [`JSON.parse()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), when this function is available:

```
var data = JSON.parse(json);
```

So you could do something like this:

```
if (window.JSON) {
    data = JSON.parse(json);
} else {
    data = eval('('+json+')');
}
```

Note the use of parenthesis in eval(). See @CMS's comment and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360356/why-the-open-quote-and-bracket-for-eval-jsonstring-when-parsing-json#3360404).

You could also use an existing library, like [this one](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) (adds JSON.parse on browsers that do not have it).

If you are using jQuery, use [`$.parseJSON()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).

Comment: You could also use `data = ((window.JSON&&JSON.parse)||eval)(json);`, which is a little more compact.

Comment: `eval(json)` will not work if the json string represents an object (e.g. `'{"foo":"bar"}'`) because the first curly brace, will be interpreted as the start of a statement *block*, not the start of an object literal, you should do: `eval('('+json+')');` to force the evaluation into an *expression context*. [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3360356#3360404). Anyway another option would be to use the `Function` constructor, IMO it's better, since `eval` makes engine optimization harder, for example: `Function('return '+json)();`.

Answer (score 3):

`JSON.parse()` is defined in most Javascript environments these days.

Answer (score 1):

try to take a look at http://www.json.org/js.html. You need something like:

```
var myObject = JSON.parse(myJSONtext, reviver);
```