# How to convert this javascript string into javascript array/object

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse JSON easily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301615/how-to-parse-json-easily)

I have this string:

```
[{text: 'First Option',  value: 'first'},{text: 'Second Option', value: 'second'},{text: 'Third Option',  value: 'third'}]
```

How do I convert it into an array/object in the same form in javascript?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Could either use `var data = JSON.parse(yourString);` or `var data = eval('(' + yourString+ ')');`

Comment: JSON.parse() will not work with this string!

Answer (score 9):

This is one of the times that `eval` actually comes in useful:

```
var x = eval(yourString);
```

But it's definitely safer to use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) as suggested by other answers.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/qAcDe/) of the `eval` version.

Comment: To properly eval a string like this, you will actually need to wrap it in parentheses, e.g. `var x = eval('(' + yourString + ')')`, otherwise you will get a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: @BradChristie - Yup, I agree! But if jQuery can't be used, and you need to support older browsers...

Comment: DO NOT USE EVAL .... its the root of all evil ... along with mushrooms !!!

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON.parse

```
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
```

Comment: invalid JSON, that string won't parse

Comment: JSON is an Object but Object isn't necessarily JSON..therefore this way is not the intended path to go.

Answer (score 0):

Just set a variable to exactly that string.

```
var new_object = [{text: 'First Option',  value: 'first'},{text: 'Second Option', value: 'second'},{text: 'Third Option',  value: 'third'}]
```

Comment: Something tells me it's not a matter of "how do I copy/paste this in javascript and get an object" (though I may be wrong).

Answer (score 0):

If you jave jQuery, you can use [`jQuery.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/). If you don't you can pull the function from the [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L536-559) and place it on your page and have the same advantages.

Comment: That is the same as `JSON.parse()` ...